# ScrollView not working in android in react-native-popover-view

Tags: android, react-native, android-scrollview, mobile-development, react-native-scrollview

After upgrading react-native to version 0.71.3, the ScrollView passed as a children to react-native-popover-view is no longer scrollable in android but works in iOS. It used to work before the upgrade of react-native version

`
import React from 'react';
import Popover from 'react-native-popover-view';

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Popover
      from={(
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>Press here to open popover!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
           {[...new Array(100)].map((item, index) => (
            <Text key={index}>{`${index}. Welcome to React native`}</Text>
           ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </Popover>
  );
```

}
`

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Did you find a fix?

Comment: No, not able to fix it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I downgraded to React Native 0.70.10 (from 0.71.10) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing:

1. `import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'`

    to `import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'`;
2. `backgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: Platform.OS === "ios" ? "transparent" : "rgba(23,31,36,0.2)" }}`